# Grafana image-rendering service - how to pass authentication details

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I recently upgraded my Grafana to v7.0.3 and started the image-rendering service as a separate pod in my k8 cluster.

I have specified both GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL  and GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL
My Grafana is configured to use the active directory (AuthN). Only authenticated users can see dashboards.
Now the problem is when my Image rendering service calls for Grafana chart I think as it is behind AD; it fails to get it (there was http 401 as well)

Can someone suggests what am I missing/how can I pass authentication details?

````
t=60&timezone=Europe%2FLondon&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmobile-grafana.mobile-grafana.svc.cluster.local%3A3000%2Fd-solo%2F000000017%2Fjenkins-performance-and-health-overview%3ForgId%3D1%26refresh%3D1m%26from%3D1591535203773%26to%3D1591546003773%26var-node%3Djenkins-stg.k8s.mobile.sbx.zone%26panelId%3D4%26width%3D1000%26height%3D500%26tz%3DEurope%252FLondon%26render%3D1&width=1000" t=2020-06-07T16:06:45+0000 lvl=eror msg="Remote rendering request failed" logger=rendering renderer=http error="403 Forbidden"
t=2020-06-07T16:06:45+0000 lvl=eror msg="Rendering failed." logger=context userId=2 orgId=1 uname="Pankaj Sainic" error="Remote rendering request failed. 403: 403 Forbidden" ```
````

Comment: Did you find a solution or a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a proxy, you have to add this "NO_PROXY" property to make it works !

```
NO_PROXY:0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1,renderer,grafana
```

`renderer` and `grafana` are here the service name declared in my docker-compose file

Comment: I removed the proxy and apparently it worked, thank you

Comment: where to add this property?

Comment: @RizwanUllah i'm adding this in my "docker-compose.yml", in "environment" section. Same place as `GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL` for example.